# deselect checkbox in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How do I clear all the selected items and deselect the Select All on Master Broker Name Test everytime I check or uncheck any item or if I select on Master Broker Company Test ?

Everytime there is changes on Master Broker Company Test then I want to clear Master Broker Name Test and deselect the select all. Thanks.

Thanks.

#html

```
<div class="report-filter-container">
      <div class="report-select-container">
        <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="full-width">
          <mat-label>Master Broker Company Test</mat-label>
          <mat-select 
            multiple 
            #selectElemMasterBrokerCompanies
            [(value)]="reportFilter.masterBrokerCompany"
            (selectionChange)="changeFilter('masterBrokerCompany',selectAllMasterBrokerCompanies)">
            <div class="idle-report-select-all-container">
              <mat-checkbox
                #selectAllMasterBrokerCompanies
                color="primary"
                (click)="toggleAllSelectionFilter('masterBrokerCompany',selectElemMasterBrokerCompanies,selectAllMasterBrokerCompanies)">
                  Select All
              </mat-checkbox>
            </div>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let f of filters.masterBrokerCompany" [value]="f.display">
              {{f.display}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      
      <div class="report-select-container">
        <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="full-width">
            <mat-label>Master Broker Name Test</mat-label>
            <mat-select 
              multiple
              #selectElemMasterBrokerNames
              [(value)]="reportFilter.masterBrokerName"
              (selectionChange)="changeFilter('masterBrokerName',selectAllMasterBrokerNames)"> `
              <div class="idle-report-select-all-container">
                <mat-checkbox
                  #selectAllMasterBrokerNames
                  color="primary"
                  (click)="toggleAllSelectionFilter('masterBrokerName',selectElemMasterBrokerNames, selectAllMasterBrokerNames)">
                    Select All
                </mat-checkbox>
              </div>
              <mat-option *ngFor="let f of filters.masterBrokerName" [value]="f.display">
                {{f.display}}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
          </mat-form-field>
      </div>
```

#tscode

```
toggleAllSelectionFilter(selectProp: string, selectElem:MatSelect, selectAll: MatCheckbox) {    
    let isSelectAllSelected = this.isAllSelected[selectProp];
    const checkSelAllOption = !isSelectAllSelected;
    selectElem.options.forEach((item: MatOption) => (checkSelAllOption)? item.select(): item.deselect());
    this.isAllSelected[selectProp] = checkSelAllOption;   
    setTimeout(()=>{
      selectAll.checked = checkSelAllOption;
    },0)    
  }
```

Comment: Can you provide a working example in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

```
   html
<input #checkboxes type="checkbox">
...
<button type="button" (click)="uncheckAll()"></button>

ts file
@ViewChildren("checkboxes") checkboxes: QueryList<ElementRef>;

uncheckAll() {
  this.checkboxes.forEach((element) => {
    element.nativeElement.checked = false;
  });
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).